# Node application: Http to Https redirection does not work for localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, redirect, https

I am adding HTTPS to a `node.js` application, while forwarding HTTP to HTTPS. I am using the following bit of code:

```
    // Trusting proxy
    self.app.enable('trust proxy');

    // Http -> Https redirection middleware
    self.app.use(function (req, res, next) {

        var schema = req.protocol.toLowerCase();
        console.log("Redirection check, schema: " + schema);

        if (schema === 'https') {
            console.log("Next");
            next();
        } else {
            var tmp = 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.url;
            console.log("Redirect to: " + tmp);
            res.redirect(tmp);
        }

    });
```

All works fine when I browse `https://localhost:8443/index.html`, the page opens fine.

But when I try `http://localhost:8443/index.html`, Chrome seems to redirect or rewrite the url to `localhost:8443/index.html` and Chrome waits for localhost eternally. There is no console message from my application. I am on under windows 7 with Chrome.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome is just hiding the `http://` portion of the URL, this is normal.

You can't run `http` and `https` on the same port.

You've specified `http` in the address, so the browser tries to connect with HTTP. The server is listening for HTTPS so it fails.

Comment: Makes sense. I was forgotting that under Openshift, you only need to listen to one port. But of course, I need to set-up a second server when on my laptop. Trying it now.